# How to make my character dash - Double Key Press

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm creating a beat em up game and so far i have the character running and jumping. I now want to make my character to dash left or right. So if the player presses the key right, right very quickly then the character will dash. How can i make this happen. This is what I have done so far.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        //Player run speed setting
        var RunSpeed:Number = 8;
        //Player key presses
        var RightKeyPress:Boolean = false;
        var LeftKeyPress:Boolean = false;
        var UpKeyPress:Boolean = false;
        //Jump variables
        var Gravity:Number = 1.5;
        var JumpPower:Number = 0;
        var CanJump:Boolean = false;
        var Jumped:Boolean = false;

        public function Player()
        {
            // constructor code
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyPressed);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,KeyReleased);
        }

        function KeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            //When Key is Down
            if (event.keyCode == 39)
            {
                RightKeyPress = true;
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 37)
            {
                LeftKeyPress = true;
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 38)
            {
                UpKeyPress = true;
            }
        }

        function Update(event:Event)
        {
            //Adding gravity to the game world
            JumpPower +=  Gravity;
            //if player is more than 300 on the y-axis
            if (this.y > 300)
            {
                //Player stays on the ground and can jump
                JumpPower = 0;
                CanJump = true;
            }

            //If on floor
            if (CanJump)
            {
                //If right key is pressed run right
                if ((RightKeyPress))
                {
                    x +=  RunSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop('Run');
                    scaleX = 1;
                }
                else if ((LeftKeyPress))
                {
                    //otherwise if left key is pressed run left
                    x -=  RunSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop('Run');
                    scaleX = -1;
                }

                if ((UpKeyPress))
                {
                    //If up key is pressed then jump
                    JumpPower = -15;
                    CanJump = false;
                    gotoAndStop('Jump');
                    Jumped = true;
                }

                //If no key is pressed stay idle
                if ((!RightKeyPress && !LeftKeyPress && CanJump))
                {
                    gotoAndStop('Idle');
                }
            }
            else if (CanJump == false)
            {
                //Other if in air and right key is pressed move right
                if ((RightKeyPress))
                {
                    x +=  RunSpeed;
                    scaleX = 1;
                }
                else if ((LeftKeyPress))
                {
                    //Otherwise if left key is pressed then move left
                    x -=  RunSpeed;
                    scaleX = -1;
                }
            }

            //If already jumped and on floor
            if (Jumped == true && CanJump)
            {
                //Cannot jump again
                CanJump = false;

                //If on floor and right key is pressed run right
                if ((RightKeyPress))
                {
                    gotoAndStop('Run');
                    scaleX = 1;
                }
                else if ((LeftKeyPress))
                {
                    //Otherwise if on floor and left key is pressed run left
                    gotoAndStop('Run');
                    scaleX = -1;
                }

                //If no key is pressed stay idle
                if ((!RightKeyPress && !LeftKeyPress))
                {
                    gotoAndStop('Idle');
                }
            }

            this.y +=  JumpPower;
        }

        function KeyReleased(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 39)
            {
                event.keyCode = 0;
                RightKeyPress = false;
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 37)
            {
                event.keyCode = 0;
                LeftKeyPress = false;
            }

            if (event.keyCode == 38)
            {
                event.keyCode = 0;
                UpKeyPress = false;
                Jumped = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you store the *previous keypress* somewhere and then you can tie that into your 'If on floor' routine, testing for a double keypress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made a little test and came up with this. It seems to be working pretty well right now. I haven't tested it in extreme lengths, but it could get you started. I'll leave it up to you to implement into your own code. Just copy/paste into a new AS3 document and watch the console

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressed);

var pressed         :Boolean = false;
var lastKeyPressed  :Number = -1;
var doubleTapDelay  :Number = 260; //-- delay in milliseconds


function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (lastKeyPressed == e.keyCode && pressed) trace("double tapped " + e.keyCode);
    lastKeyPressed = e.keyCode;
    pressed = true;
    setTimeout(function(){pressed = false},doubleTapDelay); 
}
```

**EDITED TO WORK WITH KEY_DOWN**
This seems to be working better with `KEY_DOWN`

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);

var pressed         :Boolean = false;
var lastKeyPressed  :Number = -1;
var doubleTapDelay  :Number = 260; //-- delay in milliseconds


function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyboardUp);
    if (lastKeyPressed == e.keyCode && pressed) trace("double tapped " + e.keyCode);
    lastKeyPressed = e.keyCode;
    pressed = true;
    setTimeout(function(){pressed = false},doubleTapDelay); 
}

function onKeyboardUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
}
```

**EDITED AGAIN FOR THE DEMO**

DEMO: http://ronnieswietek.com/_random/dash_example.swf

SOURCE: http://ronnieswietek.com/_random/dash_example.fla

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;

TweenPlugin.activate([BlurFilterPlugin]);


stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, permaKeyDown);

var pressed         :Boolean = false;
var lastKeyPressed  :Number = -1;
var dashAmount      :Number = 50;
var doubleTapDelay  :Number = 260; //-- delay in milliseconds

function permaKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (e.keyCode)
    {
        case 38: //-- up arrow
            char.y = char.y - 2;
            break;
        case 39: //-- right arrow
            char.x = char.x + 2;
            break;
        case 40: //-- down arrow
            char.y = char.y + 2;
            break;
        case 37: //-- left arrow
            char.x = char.x - 2;
            break;
    }
}

function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyboardUp);
    if (lastKeyPressed == e.keyCode && pressed)
    {
        trace("double tapped " + e.keyCode);
        doDash(e.keyCode);
    }
    lastKeyPressed = e.keyCode;
    pressed = true;
    setTimeout(function(){pressed = false}, doubleTapDelay);    
}

function onKeyboardUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
}

function doDash(keyCode:Number):void
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
        case 38: //-- up arrow
            TweenLite.to(char,0,{blurFilter:{blurY:50}});
            TweenLite.to(char,0.3,{blurFilter:{blurY:0},y:char.y - dashAmount,ease:Expo.easeOut});
            break;
        case 39: //-- right arrow
            TweenLite.to(char,0,{blurFilter:{blurX:50}});
            TweenLite.to(char,0.3,{blurFilter:{blurX:0},x:char.x + dashAmount,ease:Expo.easeOut});
            break;
        case 40: //-- down arrow
            TweenLite.to(char,0,{blurFilter:{blurY:50}});
            TweenLite.to(char,0.3,{blurFilter:{blurY:0},y:char.y + dashAmount,ease:Expo.easeOut});
            break;
        case 37: //-- left arrow
            TweenLite.to(char,0,{blurFilter:{blurX:50}});
            TweenLite.to(char,0.3,{blurFilter:{blurX:0},x:char.x - dashAmount,ease:Expo.easeOut});
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: One last thing, is it possible to have it on key down instead of key up. I understand why it works better on key up because if key is down it will be firing that in an infinte loop but is there a way around that

Comment: only issue I had with it being key_Down was if you press and hold it will keep firing. I suppose you can remove the key_down event listener, add a key_up listener and on key_up, readd the key_down event listener

Comment: What about this do you think this will be easier. On the first press look for a key up and on the second press it will be key down

Comment: hey, try my edit. I think that solution will work better with `KEY_DOWN` like you requested

Comment: Ok one more thing. I added a little more functionality and made a little demo with some tweening. Check out http://ronnieswietek.com/_random/dash_example.swf, the source FLA: http://ronnieswietek.com/_random/dash_example.fla `use the arrow keys`

Comment: Thank you so much that worked like a dream. Here is the demo. It works but still a lot of work to be done. Just click on play flash full screen and it will pop up.

http://megaswf.com/file/2590367

Comment: awesome! That looks cool man. Accept my answer by hitting the check mark if this is working for you

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing. I tried tackling this for weeks but no luck. How can i make it happen so if the player hits the up key once while its dashing right/left it will dash up